# Pegar registros com mais classificação em SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
comentarios
---id
---comentario
---usuario
---supermercado
---avaliacao

supermercado
---id
---nome
---endereco
---admin
```

Quero tirar a média de avaliações de cada supermercado e pegar os 3 supermercados com maior média.

Exemplo:

`Supermercado01` na tabela comentários tem avaliações:

```
4, 5, 3, 5 (média então é 4.25)
```

`Supermercado02` na tabela comentários tem avaliações:

```
1, 1, 1, 1 (média então é 1)
```

`Supermercado03` na tabela comentários tem avaliações:

```
4, 3, 3, 4 (média então é 3.5)
```

`Supermercado04` na tabela comentários tem avaliações:

```
1, 5, 2, 2 (média então é 2.5)
```

A SQL então deveria me retornar os registros do Supermercado01, Supermercado03 e Supermercado04. Daria pra ser feito em uma SQL só? Não postei nenhuma pois as que tentei foram bem falhas, e também estava tentando obter o resultado em PHP, mas o desempenho ficou tosco.

A melhor tentativa foi:

```
SELECT supermercados.nome, AVG(comentarios.avaliacao) as avaliacao
FROM supermercados, comentarios
WHERE 
supermercados.id = comentarios.supermercado ORDER BY avaliacao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente assim:

```
SELECT supermercados.nome, AVG(comentarios.avaliacao) as avaliacao
FROM 
    supermercados, comentarios
WHERE 
    supermercados.id = comentarios.supermercado 
group by
    supermercados.nome
ORDER BY 
    AVG(comentarios.avaliacao)
```

Comment: Solucionou o caso, qual seria o efeito do `GROUP BY` ? Não me lembro como é usado.

Comment: Group by agrupa pelo(s) campo(s) informados. Aí as funções de agregação (AVG, SUM, COUNT, etc) são relizadas no conjunto de registros onde os campos informados forem iguais. Neste caso para todos os supermercados de mesmo nome.

Answer (score 1):

Segue solução:

```
SELECT s.nome as 'Supermercado', AVG(c.avaliacao) as 'Média Avaliação' 
    FROM supermercado s 
        INNER JOIN comentarios c 
            ON (s.id = c.supermercado_id) 
                GROUP BY s.nome ORDER BY AVG(c.avaliacao) DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Basicamente é feita uma junção das tabelas onde apenas os supermercados que têm avaliações serão listados. Em seguida é calculado a média com os valores encontrados. O agrupamento é pelo nome, já que a seleção trás um campo e uma função (**Deve-se agrupar sempre que uma consulta mesclar campos e funções**). Por último é ordenada de maneira decrescente pela média e o LIMIT trás justamente as três maiores médias.

Espero ter ajudado. :)